# PYTHON: config use datetime as a parameter , but the time is not updated

Tags: python, datetime

````
```
today_current = datetime.now()
before_2hour = today_current + timedelta(hours=-2)
param = before_2hour.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```
````

the configuration file uses datetime as a parameter, but the time is the same each time.
how to fix it

Comment: this script called by crontab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in Python 3

```
import datetime
today_current = datetime.datetime.now()
print(today_current.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
before_2hour = today_current + datetime.timedelta(hours=-2)
param = before_2hour.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
print(param)
```

Giving:

```
$ python3 now.py
2018-09-20 13:46:35
2018-09-20 11:46:35
```

Is this not what you were expecting?

Comment: Im getting the exact same output

Comment: @Mr.shen - please put more detail in your question.